# gRPC - error: missing binary operator before token

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I have installed gRPC (1.45.2) on M1 Mac like so:

```
brew install grpc
```

Then if I add

```
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
```

Into main file of my project. Just that, nothing else. I get the following error:

```
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:22,
                 from /opt/homebrew/include/grpc/grpc.h:22,
                 from /opt/homebrew/include/grpcpp/grpcpp.h:51,
                 from /Users/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Game/AuthorativeGameManager.h:8,
                 from /Users/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Game/AuthorativeGameManager.cpp:5:
/opt/homebrew/include/grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h:241:46: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  241 | #if !(defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(cxx_thread_local))
      |                                              ^
make[3]: *** [Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Game/AuthorativeGameManager.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [WorldServer] Error 2
```

If it is important line 241 of `/opt/homebrew/include/grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h` is:

```
#if !(defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(cxx_thread_local))
```

Any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: which compiler are you using and with which flags?

Comment: @Borgleader gcc-11/g++-11 with no flags.